# Where should I computing derived data in react-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an application in which a user can add an element to timeline(simplifying to list). But this action dispatches another few actions and one of them is generated virtually elements. Actually, elements which answer to the question: Do you want here another element?

My question is where should I compute this? Should I update state in redux or compute this before rendering in mapStateToProps, for example? And if I should do it in mapStateToProps, where remember that one of these suggestions was rejected.

```js
const TimelineElement = ({type}) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'Plane':
            return <Plane/>;
        case 'Train':
            return <Train/>;
        case 'Suggestion':
            return <Suggestion/>;
        default:
            return null;

    }

};

const PlaneTravel = () => {
    return <div>Plane</div>
};

const TrainTravel = () => {
    return <div>Train</div>
};

const Suggestion = () => {
    return <div>Accommodation suggestion</div>
};


//actions
const addElement = (element) => (dispatch) => {

    //add element stuff, then:

    dispatch(addSuggestions());
    dispatch(generateReturnElements());
};

const addSuggestions = () => (dispatch) => {
    // only if conditions are met,
    // put between elements some suggestions with question:
    // do you want add accommodation element here?
};

const generateReturnElements = () => (dispatch) => {
    // if someone checks the checkbox that mean round trip,
    // i want to put additional plane or train element to timeline

};


class App extends React.Component {


    render() {
        const elements = this.props.elements.map(element => {
            return <TimelineElement type={element.type}/>
        });

        return (
            <Timeline>
                {elements}
            </Timeline>
        );

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    elements: getElements(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionsCreator({
    addElement,
}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Please post your code sample what you're actually talking about.

Comment: you need to create actions to perform the things you want to achieve. Then dispatch a action that will change state as per you need.

Comment: @root I just paste pseudocode snippet

Comment: @SarathKumar I doing it by this way already. But there is too much re-renders and I have to add some another operations like sort after add.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the derived state data by using library like reselect https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect.Try it out. It can be helpful in your application performance also. You can stop wasted re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you need. One component for a selected question can load list of answers. Rejected answer can be marked in local state - further loading the same question will start with all answers available. If you need to preserve rejections save them in global store.

I wouldn't add 'suggestions' to the list - place 'accomodations' there. Suggestions looks like view part, not data/model.

If it's wizard-like sequence - you can decompose optional features into sub-components. Listing component shows suggestion (component) conditionally between items when no accomodation added and there was no suggestion rejection (rejection is data/record) and other conditions... It could be harder than just map list into components but give you more flexibility.

Choose what you want to be persistent, store it global but optionals leave in tree structured logic (components). Of course each optional action can result in global list insertion.